# Is there anyway to "gift" D&D Insider?

Tags: dnd-4e, dnd-insider

A gift giving occasion is coming up and when my wife asked me for ideas I told her I was interested in a D&D Insider subscription. However when I went to go look up how one could give a subscription as a gift I couldn't find a way. Is there currently a way to give a D&D Insider subscription as a gift?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The short answer to this is **No, there's no official way to do that**.

The Official Boards have a thread talking about this: http://community.wizards.com/go/thread/view/75882/21799005/Damp;D_Insider_As_A_Gift

They've been talking about it for a few years it seems, but there's not a way to "send one as a gift".

I mean, you could have your wife buy you a gift Visa card or something and use that for the subscription, but that's really kinda defeating the purpose.

Comment: Yep, unfortunately there's no way to do it through wizards. Her best bet is a gift card as @Cthos mentioned, or setting up the account with her own credit card and giving you the login info as a gift. Remember to disable the subscription auto-renew (unless she wants to gift it to you **forever!**)

Comment: Sadness, twas afraid of that. Oh well!